# Through relationship using Django polymorphic model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-polymorphic

I'm trying to use a through relationship between a polymorphic and a non-polymorphic table with the the `RankedAthlete` model:

```
class ChoiceBlank(PolymorphicModel):
    pass

class ChoiceAthlete(ChoiceBlank):
    choice = models.ForeignKey('SomeModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class BetMultiple(models.Model):
    answer = models.ManyToManyField('ChoiceBlank', blank=True, through='RankedAthlete')

class RankedAthlete(models.Model):
    choiceAthlete = models.ForeignKey('ChoiceBlank', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bet = models.ForeignKey('BetMultiple', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.IntegerField()
```

This doesn't work because `RankedAthlete` expects a `ChoiceBlank` and a `ValueError` is raised when I create one. Conversely, I can't migrate my db if I replace choice with a `ChoiceAthlete`.

[Django-polymorphic](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) doc doesn't mention my use case, is it unsupported? Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to not be possible.
As an alternative, since I only need one type of using an ordered `answer`, I created a model specificaly for it using the child model rather than the parent model and changed `RankedAthlete` accordingly:

```
class BetMultipleOrdered(models.Model):
    answer = models.ManyToManyField('ChoiceAthlete', blank=True, through='RankedAthlete')

class RankedAthlete(models.Model):
    choiceAthlete = models.ForeignKey('ChoiceAthlete', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bet = models.ForeignKey('BetMultiple', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rank = models.IntegerField()
```

Another alternative would be to use [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes).